# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 c++ visual studio code. game snakes and ladders

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

this error appears to me in two classes specifically and referenced in the main. Honestly, I don't know what happened.

```
"Boxes::fillLadder(char**, int**, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      Boxes::fill(char**, int**, int, int) in SnakesAndLadders2-455af6.o
      Board::draw(char**, int**, int, int) in SnakesAndLadders2-455af6.o
  "Boxes::fillSnake(char**, int**, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      Boxes::fill(char**, int**, int, int) in SnakesAndLadders2-455af6.o
      Board::draw(char**, int**, int, int) in SnakesAndLadders2-455af6.o
  "Boxes::Boxes()", referenced from:
      Board::draw(char**, int**, int, int) in SnakesAndLadders2-455af6.o
      _main in SnakesAndLadders2-455af6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

This is class Boxes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Boxes{

    public:
    Boxes(); 

    void fill(char **board, int **positions, int y, int x);
    void fillLadder(char **board, int **positions, int y, int x, int lenght);
    void fillSnake(char **board, int **positions, int y, int x, int lenght);
};

void Boxes::fill(char **board, int **positions, int y, int x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < x; w++)
        {
            board[i][w] = 'N';
            positions[i][w] = 0;
        }  
    }

    if (y % 2 != 0)
    {
        board[0][x - 1] = 'O';
    }
    else
    {
        board[0][0] = 'O';
    }

    board[y - 1][0] = 'O';

    if (y < 8)
    {
        fillLadder(board, positions, y - 1, 2, y / 2);
        fillLadder(board, positions, y / 2, 4, 2);

        fillSnake(board, positions, 0, 1, -1 * y / 2 + 1);
    }

    if (y >= 8 && y <= 12)
    {
        fillLadder(board, positions, y - 1, 3, 3);
        fillLadder(board, positions, 4, x - 3, 2);
        fillLadder(board, positions, 2, x - 2, 2);

        fillSnake(board, positions, 0, 4, -4);
        fillSnake(board, positions, 4, x - 4, -4);
        fillSnake(board, positions, 4, 0, -3);
    }

    if (y > 12)
    {
        fillLadder(board, positions, y - 1, 3, 6);
        fillLadder(board, positions, 6, x - 3, 5);
        fillLadder(board, positions, 7, x - 2, 6);
        fillLadder(board, positions, 9, 3, 3);

        fillSnake(board, positions, 0, 4, -7);
        fillSnake(board, positions, 4, x - 4, -6);
        fillSnake(board, positions, 7, 0, -3);
        fillSnake(board, positions, 5, 2, -2);
    }
}
```

This is class Board

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Boxes.h"

using namespace std;

class Board{

    public:

    void loop(char **board, int **positions, int y, int x);
    void draw(char **board, int **positions, int y, int x);

};

void Board::loop(char **board, int **positions, int x, int y)
{
    player1.location = 0;
    player2.location = 0;

    player1.level = y - 1;
    player2.level = y - 1;

    bool game = true;

    Player p;
    bool playerFlag;
    int &movement = movement;

    void Movement(int &movement, bool playerFlag);
    {
        Dice dice;
        int status = 0;
        if (playerFlag == true)
        {
            std::cout << "Player 1: Press 1 to roll the dice." << std::endl;
            cin >> status;

            if (status == 1)
            {
                dice.roll();
                movement = dice.roll();
                std::cout << "Player 1 rolled a: " << dice.roll() << std::endl;
            }
        }

        if (playerFlag == false)
        {
            std::cout << "Player 2: Press 2 to roll the dice." << std::endl;
            cin >> status;

            if (status == 2)
            {
                dice.roll();
                movement = dice.roll();
                std::cout << "Player 2 rolled a: " << dice.roll() << std::endl;
            } 
        }
    }

    while (game == true)
    {
        p.Movement(player1.movement, true);
        p.logic(board, positions, y, x, player1.movement, player1.location, player1.level, player1.movestatus);

        if (p.checkWin(y, x, player1.location, player1.level) == true)
        {
            std::cout << "Player 1 HAS WON THE GAME !!!!!!" << std::endl;
            game = false;
        }
        else
        {
            p.updatePlayerLevel(positions, y, x, player1.location, player1.level, player1.movestatus);
            board[player1.level][player1.location] = player1.symbol;
            draw(board, positions, y, x);
        }
        if (player2.on == true)
        {
            p.Movement(player2.movement, false);
            p.logic(board, positions, y, x, player2.movement, player2.location, player2.level, player2.movestatus);

            if (p.checkWin(y, x, player2.location, player2.level) == true)
            {
                std::cout << "Player 2 HAS WON THE GAME !!!!!!" << std::endl;
                game = false;
            }
            else
            {
                p.updatePlayerLevel(positions, y, x, player2.location, player2.level, player2.movestatus);
                board[player2.level][player2.location] = player2.symbol;
                draw(board, positions, y, x);
            }
        }
    }
}


void Board::draw(char **board, int **positions, int y, int x)
{
    Boxes bx;
    if (y % 2 != 0)
    {
        board[0][x - 1] = 'O';
    }
    else
    {
        board[0][0] = 'O';
    }

    board[y - 1][0] = 'O';

    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        if ((y - 1) > 9)
        {
            std::cout << y - 1 << " ⎪" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << y - 1 << " ⎪" << std::endl;
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < x; y++)
        {
            std::cout << board[i][y] << " " << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "  " << std::endl;
    }

    if (y < 8)
    {
        bx.fillLadder(board, positions, y - 1, 2, y / 2);
        bx.fillLadder(board, positions, y / 2, 4, 2);
        bx.fillLadder(board, positions, 0, 1, -1 * y / 2 + 1);
    }

    if (y >= 8 && y <= 12)
    {
        bx.fillLadder(board, positions, y - 1, 3, 3);
        bx.fillLadder(board, positions, 4, x - 3, 2);
        bx.fillLadder(board, positions, 2, x - 2, 2);

        bx.fillSnake(board, positions, 0, 4, -4);
        bx.fillSnake(board, positions, 4, x - 4, -4);
        bx.fillSnake(board, positions, 4, 0, -3);
    }

    if (y > 12)
    {
        bx.fillLadder(board, positions, y - 1, 3, 6);
        bx.fillLadder(board, positions, 6, x - 3, 5);
        bx.fillLadder(board, positions, 7, x - 2, 6);
        bx.fillLadder(board, positions, 9, 3, 3);

        bx.fillSnake(board, positions, 0, 4, -7);
        bx.fillSnake(board, positions, 4, x - 4, -6);
        bx.fillSnake(board, positions, 7, 0, -3);
        bx.fillSnake(board, positions, 5, 2, -2);
    }
}
```

And the main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include "Board.h"



using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Boxes f;
    Board bo;

    std::cout << "****** SNAKES AND LADDERS ******" << std::endl;


    int size_y;
    int size_x;

    std::cout << "What size board do you want? Pick the number of rows and columns." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "For balance, best size is 10x10." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Rows: " << std::endl;
    cin >> size_y;
    std::cout << "Columns: " << std::endl;
    cin >> size_x;

    int flag;
    std::cout << "Press 2 if you want to play multiplayer (2 players). Press 1 for single player." << std::endl;
    cin >> flag;

    if (flag == 2)
    {
        player2.on = true;
    }
    std::cout << "Player 1: Select a letter/number on the keyboard for your character." << std::endl;
    cin >> player1.symbol;

    if (player2.on == true)
    {
        std::cout << "PLayer 2: Select a letter/number on the keyboard for your character." << std::endl;
        cin >> player2.symbol;
    }

    system("CLS");

    char **board;
    board = new char *[size_y];

    int **position_status;
    position_status = new int *[size_y];

    for (int i = 0; i < size_y; i++)
    {
        board[i] = new char [size_x];
        position_status[i] = new int [size_x];
    }

    f.fill(board, position_status, size_y, size_x);
    bo.draw(board, position_status, size_y, size_x);
    bo.loop(board, position_status, size_y, size_x);

    char stop;
    std::cout << "Press e to end the programme." << std::endl;
    cin >> stop;

    for (int i = 0; i < size_y; i++)
    {
        delete[] board[i];
        delete[] position_status[i];
    }

    delete board;
    delete position_status;

    return 0;
}
```

This code is about a snakes and ladders game.
Let me know if you need the class player because I used it on the class board.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Did you look at any of the suggested answers? This appears a lot and has been answered.

Comment: So three functions have been listed as 'missing' `Boxes::fillLadder`, `Boxes::fillSnake` and `Boxes::Boxes`. Can you point to them in the code? Because I don't see them.

Comment: This appears to be nothing more complicated than you've declared three functions but then failed to write the code for them.

Comment: Those are the functions. void fill(char **board, int **positions, int y, int x);
void fillLadder(char **board, int **positions, int y, int x, int lenght);
void fillSnake(char **board, int **positions, int y, int x, int lenght);

Comment: John, you were right I only write the function fill but not the other ones thanks.